# Make flexible take entire space in horizontal mode

Tags: flutter

I have two expanded in a row. My application will run in horizontal mode by default. Problem is I turned one of the `Expanded` to take up entire screen space by wrapping it with a column. But the other one doesn't work.

Here's what I'm taking about
[image]

Here's my code:

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Row(
                // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        // fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onPanUpdate: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                RenderBox renderBox =
                                    context.findRenderObject();
                                points.add(TouchPoints(
                                    points: renderBox
                                        .globalToLocal(details.globalPosition),
                                    paint: Paint()
                                      ..strokeCap = strokeType
                                      ..isAntiAlias = true
                                      ..color =
                                          selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                                      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                              });
                            },
                            onPanStart: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                RenderBox renderBox =
                                    context.findRenderObject();
                                points.add(TouchPoints(
                                    points: renderBox
                                        .globalToLocal(details.globalPosition),
                                    paint: Paint()
                                      ..strokeCap = strokeType
                                      ..isAntiAlias = true
                                      ..color =
                                          selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                                      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                              });
                            },
                            onPanEnd: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                points.add(null);
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  CustomPaint(
                                    size: Size.infinite,
                                    painter: MyPainter(pointsList: points),
                                  ),
                                  IgnorePointer(
                                    ignoring: true,
                                    child:
                                        displayImage(context, widget.imagePath),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      child: displayMenu(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Does putting the Expanded outside of the Column instead of inside and making the Column crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is because of height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75
when set height for one of your children in column or row it makes the minimum height for column or row.
disable it to work everything fine